# systemctl strange error: Invalid arguments

Tags: django, ubuntu, systemctl, daphne

Here's my service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Daphne Interface

[Service]
ExecStartPre=cd /home/git/hsfzmun/server
ExecStart=/bin/bash/ -c "cd /home/git/hsfzmun/server && /home/git/virtualenvs/hsfzmun/bin/daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8001 -v2 config.asgi:channel_layer"
Restart=always
KillSignal=SIGQUIT
Type=notify
NotifyAccess=all

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When I execute `sudo systemctl start daphnei` I get:

```
Failed to start daphnei.service: Unit daphnei.service is not loaded properly: Invalid argument.
See system logs and 'systemctl status daphnei.service' for details.
```

And the result of `systemctl status daphnei.service`:

```
* daphnei.service - Daphne Interface
   Loaded: error (Reason: Invalid argument)
   Active: inactive (dead) (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2017-02-13 19:55:10 CST; 13min ago
 Main PID: 16667 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

What's wrong? I am using Ubuntu Server 16.04.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe you've figured it out by now, but there's an extra `/` after `/bin/bash` in your `ExecStart` line.

I may have a slightly newer version of `systemd` -- when I tried it, the output of `systemctl status` included this message:

```
Executable path specifies a directory, ignoring: /bin/bash/ -c "cd /home/git/hsfzmun/server && /home/git/virtualenvs/hsfzmun/bin/daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8001 -v2 config.asgi:channel_layer"
```

Also, you might consider using a `WorkingDirectory` line in the service, instead of `cd &&`

Answer (score 18):

Generally, to debug exact cause of "Invalid argument", you can use:

`sudo systemd-analyze verify daphnei.service`

or in case of user's local service:

`sudo systemd-analyze --user verify daphnei.service`

Comment: "Unknown operation 'verify'"

Comment: check a man of ur particular systemd-analyze version, it should definitely be a known command and correct syntax: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-analyze.html